In C struct, why packed,aligned seems to do padding?
In C struct, why packed,aligned seems to do padding?
I have to read a bunch of MSB/LSB bytes from a remote device using i2c. As all device data are bytes, I use uint8_t which represent exactly 8 bits that is 1 byte.
Now I need to be sure that the struct is packed (i.e. no "hole" between elements in the struct) unless I would not read data as they are generated in the remote device.
Then, I added aligned for performance (i.e. allow the CPU read the struct with minimum memory access).
As explained here Structure padding and packing, padding aligns structure members to "natural" address boundaries, and, packing prevents from padding.
This simple test surprised me:
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

$ cat dumb.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // uint8_t

struct struct1 {
  uint8_t msb;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct struct2 {
  uint8_t msb;
} __attribute__((packed,aligned(4)));

struct struct3 {
  uint8_t msb;
  uint8_t lsb;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct struct4 {
  uint8_t msb;
  uint8_t lsb;
} __attribute__((packed,aligned(4)));

int main(void) {
  struct struct1 s1;
  printf("sizeof(s1) %zu\n", sizeof(s1));
  struct struct2 s2;
  printf("sizeof(s2) %zu\n", sizeof(s2));
  struct struct3 s3;
  printf("sizeof(s3) %zu\n", sizeof(s3));
  struct struct4 s4;
  printf("sizeof(s4) %zu\n", sizeof(s4));
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -o dumb dumb.c

$ ./dumb 
sizeof(s1) 1
sizeof(s2) 4
sizeof(s3) 2
sizeof(s4) 4


aligned seems to "pad the end of the struct": is this expected?

I expected s2 to begin at a multiple-of-4-bytes memory address, but, to have size 1.
I expected s4 to begin at a multiple-of-4-bytes memory address, but, to have size 2.

I read these bytes from a remote device so each byte is transferred using i2c from the device to the PC: now for performance, is it better to go packed only to avoid "extra padding at the end", or, it is better to go packed,aligned transferring and reading extra unused "padded-at-the-end" bytes each time there is a transfer?

I think you're misinterpreting what aligned does.

"I expected s2 to begin at a multiple-of-4-bytes memory address, but, to have size 1.": How would you expect struct struct2 s2[2]; to work then? I think you want the aligned attribute on the variable declaration, not the type.

Generally, structs are unsuitable for representing data packages, as you just found out.

The aligned attribute on a struct declaration means that any instance of the struct must begin at an aligned address.
That also means that if you have an array of structs, the struct may require trailing padding so that each member of the array is properly aligned.
While the packed attribute will minimize any padding used in the struct, such padding can't necessarily be eliminated completely when used in conjunction with aligned.
So for example if you had this declaration:
struct struct2 s2[2];

If you didn't have trailing padding then s2[1] wouldn't be properly aligned.

So this means you generally can not have a struct both packed and aligned as each one comes with its own constrant. So one need to choose packed or aligned.

@fghoussen, packed and aligned together may give you a different layout than either one does alone.  In particular, I anticipate that it will generally give all padding at the end, without any between members, in cases where aligned alone has internal padding in some places and packed has none at all.  But yes, alignment constrains structure layout size such that padding may be required.


In C struct, why packed,aligned seems to do padding?

Because the alignment requirement of a data type must divide its size.  Otherwise, you could not form arrays of that type.  If you force a specific alignment requirement, then the compiler may need to adjust the size (by adding padding).

I have to read a bunch of MSB/LSB bytes from a remote device using i2c. As all device data are bytes, I use uint8_t which represent exactly 8 bits that is 1 byte.
Now I need to be sure that the struct is packed (i.e. no "hole" between elements in the struct) unless I would not read data as they are generated in the remote device.

An arguably more natural way of doing this would be to read your MSB/LSB pairs each into a single uint16_t, which you can be sure has no internal padding.  And since you describe the pairs as you do, I suppose you might want to interpret the pairs as 16-bit numbers, which can then be conveniently achieved via the ntohs() function.

Then, I added aligned for performance (i.e. allow the CPU read the struct with minimum memory access).

That is very likely a premature optimization. Any delay resulting from misalignment is likely to be completely overwhelmed by your I/O overhead.

padding aligns structure members to "natural" address boundaries,

More or less.  That's the normal purpose of padding between members in structure layouts, but it's not an inherent characteristic of such padding, nor is that the only kind of location for padding.

and, packing prevents from padding.

Not exactly.  The precise meaning of packing-control directives vary among C implementations, but you're using GCC, whose definition is:

packed
This attribute, attached to struct, union, or C++ class type definition, specifies that each of its each members [...] is placed to minimize the memory required.

furthermore,

Specifying this attribute for struct and union types is equivalent to specifying the packed attribute on each of the structure or union members.

... in which context,

The packed attribute specifies that a structure member should have the smallest possible alignment—one bit for a bit-field and one byte otherwise.

So no, it it does not speak directly to padding at all.  Forcing the alignment requirement for (non-bitfield) members to 1 byte does result in them being laid out without any leading padding, but that says nothing about whether any padding follows.

aligned seems to "pad the end of the struct": is this expected?

Yes, as already discussed.  And this is does not conflict with the definition of packed.


I expected s2 to begin at a multiple-of-4-bytes memory address, but, to have size 1.
I expected s4 to begin at a multiple-of-4-bytes memory address, but, to have size 2.


Again, a type with an alignment requirement of 4 will have a size that is a multiple of 4, so your expectations were incorrect.  However, I think GCC allows you to align individual variables, so if you really want what you describe, then you should be able to achieve it, for those particular variables, by moving the aligned attribute from the types to the corresponding variables:
  struct struct1 s2 __attribute__((aligned(4)));
  struct struct3 s4 __attribute__((aligned(4)));

But again, I think you're worrying far to much about this. Moving bytes across your i2c interface is going to consume an overwhelming amount of the time here.

I read these bytes from a remote device so each byte is transferred using i2c from the device to the PC: now for performance, is it better to go packed only to avoid "extra padding at the end", or, it is better to go packed,aligned transferring and reading extra unused "padded-at-the-end" bytes each time there is a transfer?

Who says you would read anything into any structure padding?  You shouldn't.  If you're reading bytes one pair at a time then you wouldn't anyway.  If you're reading sequences of multiple byte pairs in a single operation then you cannot have padding.  But again, you seem to be making things much harder than they need to be.  I would skip the structures and use type uint16_t for the byte pairs.  Especially so if you're reading many of them together, in which case you would use a uint16_t[].  Supposing that you want to interpret each pair as a 16-bit number, post process each one with ntohs() after the read, before doing anything else.
If the result is not fast enough then profile it to determine where the bottleneck is, and work on that.
